# How to select on click the hovered element not the hover element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hover

I am using jquery to drag and drop some element and for some too small element i display hover a div with info content.
My problem is when i want to drag this element i select the hover div not the hovered div and i need to drag the hovered div...

Actually i am using this to create my hover div:

```
 $(".ghost_for[data-id='"+value+"']").append("<div class='hiddenTextjob' unselectable='on' id='displayHoraires_"+value+"'>" + firstTemp + "-" + lastTemp + "<br /> idjob: "+value+"</div>");
```

and i display the hover element by using css:

```
.ghost_for:hover > .hiddenTextjob{
        display: block;
        background-color:#000;
        color:#FFF;
        width:72px;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
```

Do you have a solution to drag the hovered element rather than the hover element?

thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the focus on the hover div on click. Like:

```
  $( "#target" ).focus();
```

Comment: i try this:
`$(document).on('mousedown', ".hiddenTextjob", function(){
                $(this.closest('div.ghost_for')).focus();
            });`

But not work... i must to get the drag handler of the hovered element